# How can I manually register an uninstaller in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, windows, installation

The goal is to install MSYS2 (with various packages) on one online PC, and copy the install to multiple offline PCs. This is AFAICT legal (MSYS2 is open source) and mostly easy. MSYS2 avoids using the registry as much as possible and doesn't have separate folders in AppData, so it's mostly just copying the c:\msys64 folder and recreating the start menu items.

However, it would be nice to register the uninstaller properly. In the registry that involves a GUID, and I'm not sure where that comes from, so I'm not entirely comfortable just forcing that information into the registry manually.

Is there a tool included in Windows that will correctly register an uninstaller? One that finds/generates that GUID the way it's supposed to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure.  Run:

`REG ADD HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\AnyText /v UninstallString /t REG_SZ /d "C:\Program Files\Whatever\Uninstall.exe"`

(Or, use RegEdit.)

The "AnyText" can be a GUID, or any other text.  Windows simply scans for subkeys under Uninstall

As for creating a GUID, there is no official way.  A GUID stands for "Global Unique Identifier".  At least, officially.  In my opinion, it's better to think of it as "Globally Unique-ish Identifier".  The idea is that it has so many digits, that effective randomization is likely to create a number so unique that nobody else will ever come up with the same number.  (Or, even if they did, if some major government agency in London came up with the same GUID as some person's basement in Moscow, the likelihood of them every noticing is so extremely low that they will never know.)  There is no central database that you need to register with in order to use a GUID, and people can use different methods if they want to, as long as the end result is hopefully going to be so unique that nobody else will end up with the same GUID.

There may be some tools that generate GUIDs, like some programming environments that create executable files, but since it's so very de-centralized in nature, there's no reason why you would need to utilize such a thing.

Comment: OK - I guess it was a little paranoid worrying that maybe the GUID had to be consistent with something somewhere.